# Shiny rcharts multiple chart output

Tags: r, rcharts, shiny-server

How can I overwrite the output display options with running multiple charts with shiny and rchart so the output result is a 2x2 matrix type grid layout.

```
require(rCharts)
require(shiny)
require(data.table)
runApp(list(
  ui = mainPanel( span="span6", 
    showOutput("chart2", "Highcharts"),
    showOutput("chart3", "Highcharts"),
    showOutput("chart4", "Highcharts")
    ),
  server = function(input, output){
      output$chart3 <- renderChart({
      a <- hPlot(Pulse ~ Height, data = MASS::survey, type = "bubble", title = "Zoom demo", subtitle = "bubble chart", size = "Age", group = "Exer")
      a$chart(zoomType = "xy")
      a$chart(backgroundColor = NULL)
      a$set(dom = 'chart3')
      return(a)
    })
    output$chart2 <- renderChart({
      survey <- as.data.table(MASS::survey)
      freq <- survey[ , .N, by = c('Sex', 'Smoke')]
      a <- hPlot(x = 'Smoke', y = 'N', data = freq, type = 'column', group = 'Sex')
      a$chart(backgroundColor = NULL)
      a$set(dom = 'chart2')
      return(a)
    })
    output$chart4 <- renderChart({
      survey <- as.data.table(MASS::survey)
      freq <- survey[ , .N, by = c('Smoke')]
      a <- hPlot(x = "Smoke", y = "N", data = freq, type = "pie")
      a$plotOptions(pie = list(size = 150))
      a$chart(backgroundColor = NULL)
      a$set(dom = 'chart4')
      return(a)
    })
  }
))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change ui to:

```
ui = bootstrapPage(mainPanel( 
      div(class = "row",
        div(showOutput("chart2", "Highcharts"), class = "span4"),
        div(showOutput("chart3", "Highcharts"), class = "span4")
      ),
      div(class = "row",
        div(showOutput("chart4", "Highcharts"), class = "span4")
      )
    ))
```

Add `bootstrapPage` to tell shiny to use the bootstrap library. Look at http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html to get an idea of "scaffolding". `mainPanel` has a width option which defaults to 8. 
This is span8 in bootstrap. 
The above code is not ideal but hopefully its a start.

EDIT: For full screen

```
ui = bootstrapPage(mainPanel(width = 12,  
      div(class = "row",
        div(showOutput("chart2", "Highcharts"), class = "span6"),
        div(showOutput("chart3", "Highcharts"), class = "span6")
      ),
      div(class = "row",
        div(showOutput("chart4", "Highcharts"), class = "span6")
      )
    ))
```

note that mainPanel(..., width = width) is just a convenience function for div with a span of width.

A screenshot of the result:

[image]

Comment: thanks for that, really helpful. On the Shiny side of things, does mainPanel alone extend to the full screen? Or do you have to use something like sidePanel but alter the span to something like span6 for sidePanel and MainPanel?

Comment: `mainPanel` is basically just setting up a `div` with an option `width` which sets the span. If you change mainPanel adding the option `width = 12` and change the class on the inner divs to `span6` you should get what you want.

Comment: @jdharrison, with your permission added a screenshot of the result, nice!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that is native to R Shiny (without the outside knowledge of HTML), is to use the ideas of columns.

```
ui = mainPanel(fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(width=6, 
             showOutput("chart2", "Highcharts"),
             showOutput("chart3", "Highcharts")
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(width=6, 
             showOutput("chart4", "Highcharts") 
        )
      )
    )
  )),
```