# How Do I put Multiple Charts on the Same Graph rCharts High Charts

Tags: r, graphics, plot, highcharts, rcharts

Using rCharts wrapper for High Charts, how would I plot different charts onto the same graph? In other words, I would essentially want one chart, let's call it h1, to be its own chart with its own x-axis and y-axis and another chart h2 to have its own x-axis and y-axis, but I would like to be able to return some final chart, say h3, that stacks h1 and h2 into one object that I can return with my plotting function. Is this possible? I don't have an example because I don't have an understanding of how to really approach this problem right now. Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide your ui.R and server.R to get better idea of what you are trying to do ?
You can find a possible answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895321/shiny-rcharts-multiple-chart-output

Comment: Hi Shiva, Thanks for looking into it. I have the exact same format as the answer in that link, but I wanted my output to only have one stacked graph rather than requiring two outputs rendering one graph each. I'm planning to use these for animation, and when I use two separate graphs, it slows down my application, so I believe one stacked graph has the potential to be quicker.

Comment: Looks like you got answer! Good luck with that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about the rCharts side of it.

But to do this in Highcharts, you can specify multiple y axes, specifying a `top` an `height` property, and multiple x axes, using the `offset` property.

Then you assign an `xAxis` and a `yAxis` for each data set.

```
xAxis: [{ 
    offset : -120    
},{

}],
yAxis: [{ 
    title  : { text: 'Y Axis 0' },
    height : 100        
},{
    title  : { text: 'Y Axis 1' },
    offset : 0,
    top    : 200,
    height : 100
}]
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/nq6fphn8/

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I'm looking for! I should be able to translate this into R. Thanks for the idea!